# Calculating annual growth

Tags: python

I am trying to set a formula for getting the annual growth rate turnover for a business and the number doesn't come out right.

Below is my code. What is incorrect?

```
#8)Annual Growth rate in percentage

#Number of years
ny = 10

#Present Turnover
pt = 310

#Past turnover value
ppt = 205

m =(pt/ppt)

#AGR = Annual Growth rate
agr = float((m**1/ny)-1)*100
print(agr)
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: In code it should be `agr = float((m ** ( 1.0 / ny ) - 1) * 100`

Comment: Given the different ways decimals are handled between python2 and python3, which version do you use ?

Comment: To format it as source code, you highlight the part of the text that is code and press Ctrl+K (in the StackOverflow editor), thereby indenting it, which is the markdown way of designating a code block.

Comment: @blubberdiblub, thanks, learned sumthin new. (First day on python)

Comment: @Tnerual , I use version 3. Worked out though, was just the parenthesis missing.

Comment: @PM 2Ring, ok done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot a pair of brackets. In the formula for the annual growth rate, `m**1/ny` should be `m**(1/ny)`. Otherwise you just do `m**1` and divide the result by the number of years. That doesn't get you the right answer of course.

Comment: Yeah, I had some trouble getting the formatting right for the text with a double asterisk. I figured it out now, though, it is fixed.

Comment: Thanks alot! 

When i used asterix it work but not with the  power sign, see below error text.

    agr = float(m^(1/ny)-1)*100

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'float' and 'float'

Comment: @Lotusline In Python, the `^` operator does a bitwise [Exclusive-OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) operation. You need `**` for powers; there's also a `pow` function. (FWIW, the `**` operator also gets used for dictionary unpacking, but in practice that doesn't lead to confusion because it's always clear from the context which meaning is intended).